# Transversal intersection of graph and diagonal

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a smooth map.
Let $$G=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2n}\ \mid y=f(x)\}$$ be the graph of $f$ and let $$D=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2n}\ \mid x=y\}$$ be the diagonal.
My question is: when do $G$ and $D$ have a transverse intersection (as submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$)?
I know that two submanifolds $N_1,N_2$ of $M$ have a transverse intersection if for every $p \in N_1 \cap N_2$, the tangent spaces $T_pN_1$ and $T_pN_2$ span $T_pM$. Now, in my case, the intersection is
$$G \cap D=\{(x,x) \in \mathbb{R}^n\ \mid x=f(x)\},$$
the set of fixed points of $f$. I am not sure what to do next.

Comment: The tangent space of $G$ at a point $(x,f(x))$ is the graph of the linear map $df_x\colon\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$. Of course, the tangent space to $D$ at a point $(x,x)$ is $D$ itself, as it is a linear subspace. You're now left with the linear algebra task of figuring out when the graphs of two linear functions intersect transversely.

Comment: As another hint, you might think about it from the point of view of the eigenvalues of $df_x$